# How to combine rows in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a large dataset that looks kind of like this

```
ID | X2 | X3 | X4|
1  | abc| abc| abc|
1  | xyz| xyz| xyz|
2  | abc| abc| abc|
```

and I want to combine the rows by id number (kind of like you would use merge if they were different dataframes) to look like this:

```
ID | X1 | X2 | X3| X1.b| X2.b|X3.b|
1  | abc| abc| abc| xyz| xyz| xyz|
2  | abc| abc| abc| NA | NA | NA |
```

I've tried the reshape function, but the way it works with timevar doesn't fit my data well (I think?)

I'd be grateful to hear others' ideas!

Answer (score 1):

We can do the `pivot_wider` directly on multiple columns after creating a sequence column by ID

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(X2, X3, X4), names_sep=".")
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#     ID X2.1  X2.2  X3.1  X3.2  X4.1  X4.2 
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 abc   xyz   abc   xyz   abc   xyz  
#2     2 abc   <NA>  abc   <NA>  abc   <NA>
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID ~ rowid(ID), value.var = c("X2", "X3", "X4"), sep=".")
#   ID X2.1 X2.2 X3.1 X3.2 X4.1 X4.2
#1:  1  abc  xyz  abc  xyz  abc  xyz
#2:  2  abc <NA>  abc <NA>  abc <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2), X2 = c("abc", "xyz", "abc"), 
    X3 = c("abc", "xyz", "abc"), X4 = c("abc", "xyz", "abc")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hi! The dataset is rather large, and that comes with a few problems. 1) making the c(X2, X3,) etc. is a bit of a pain, because there dozens of variables. 2) I get the error message "vector memory exhausted" when I try to run this code

Comment: @DanBromberg Try with `dcast` on a fresh session.  Should be faster. INstead of typing, you can just the `names(df1)[2:4]` in `value.var`

Comment: Sorry for the million questions; it is saying it will only accept types character or NULL. I have other types of data in the set as well (dates and integers) @akrun

Comment: @DanBromberg  Depends on which method you are using.  if it is `data.table` and you want other columns as well, then it needs to be taken care of in the formula expressioni i.e. `ID + somecol ~ rowid(ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can get the data in long format, create a unique value for every `ID` and `name` and get the data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, name) %>%
  mutate(row = paste0(name, letters[row_number()])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
#     ID X2a   X3a   X4a   X2b   X3b   X4b  
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 abc   abc   abc   xyz   xyz   xyz  
#2     2 abc   abc   abc   NA    NA    NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L), X2 = c("abc", "xyz", "abc"
), X3 = c("abc", "xyz", "abc"), X4 = c("abc", "xyz", "abc")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```